# Log4Net 1.2.10 public key conflict

Tags: nhibernate, crystal-reports, log4net, public-key

I have an app that uses both NHibernate and Crystal Reports, NHibernate.dll reference Log4Net 1.2.10.0 (PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4)

After upgrading Crystal to ver 13.0.2000 we now have a problem, crystaldecisions.shared.dll now references Log4Net 1.2.10.0 as well, but it seems that the good folk at Crystal Decisions have made the "interesting" decision to recompile 1.2.10.0 leaving the version number the same, but giving it a ***new public key*** (692fbea5521e1304) and installed it into the GAC.

So my question is...How to install these log4net assemblies side by side? or trick one of the other assemblies (NHibernate or Crystal) into using the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to install the standard log4net into the GAC as well.  This will allow both versions to be loaded by the assembly loader.  Alternately you could recompile NHibernate to use the version crystal does, but you'd have to do that from now on moving forward, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Very annoying that I now have to register the standard version of log4Net into the GAC, but this seems to be my only real option.